# How to parse efficiently a Rest Api response that evolve each time

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I am not a programmer, then I lake basic knowledge.

I want to create a desktop app, a dictionary, you search a word, you have a short definition.

I use those guys.

https://api.lexicala.com/

Then here is part of my script bellow.

My problem is that for each part I search for, the meaning of the word, its nature, etc.

I have to make this decapsulation code lines.
// Edit: decapsulation=deserialization

```
response.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("headword").get("text")
```

If the Json was not changing each time, no problem, but it does.

An Adjective, and a noun change completely the structure, and I get an error.

A Json Object is now a Json Array.

I would like to know if there is a simple way, either Jackson, or Gson or Json to
simply ask something like

```
Json.Parse (JsonResponse);
get("Definition");
```

Instead of

```
Object Resultat4 = response.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("senses").getJSONObject(0).get("definition");
```

And have the content only, without passing by all this changing lines of codes.

Thanks you to help me on this.

```
//Values

String motacherch = "grand";



public void  gettest(){



   HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=fr&text="+motacherch)
           .basicAuth("user", "password")
           .asJson();

   JSONObject responsejson = (JSONObject) response.getBody().getObject();
   System.out.println( responsejson);


   Object Resultat = response.getBody().getObject().get("n_results");
   System.out.println( "Le nombre de resultats est:"+ Resultat);


    Object Resultat2 = response.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("headword").get("text");
    System.out.println( "Le mot que l'on cherche est: "+ Resultat2);
    Object Resultat3 = response.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("headword").get("pos");
    System.out.println( "C'est un: "+ Resultat3);
    Object Resultat4 = response.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("senses").getJSONObject(0).get("definition");

    System.out.println( "Definition: "+ Resultat4);


    System.out.println( "---------------------------------------------" );

HttpResponse<JsonNode> response2 = Unirest.get("https://dictapi.lexicala.com/users/me")
        .basicAuth("", "")
        .asJson();
    //System.out.println( response2.getBody());
    JSONObject responsejson2 = response2.getBody().getObject();
    JSONObject results = responsejson2.getJSONObject("usage").getJSONObject("today");
    Object results2=results.get("count");
    System.out.println( results2);
```

}

Comment: OK, will comment my own question, I am making my home work: 
https://devqa.io/how-to-parse-json-in-java/

Comment: Hooo we say "deserialization", for russian doll extraction thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to parse (deserialise) the json to a java `Map<String, Object>`, which always succeeds (the values may themselves be maps) using your favourite library (try Jackson or gson).

Then examine the map’s keys to figure out what to do with it.

The harder, but more “correct” way is to deserialise to a variety of classes chosen by the attributes of the payload, but in this case I wouldn’t, as the API design sounds a little flakey.

---

Here’s some code to parse json to a map:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Map<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr, LinkedHashMap.class); // LinkedHashMap will preserve order
```

To make accessing map values easier, you may find this helper method that does the cast by inference handy:

```
static <T> T getValue(Map<String, Object> map, String key) {
    return (T)map.get(key);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = getValue(map, "results"); // no cast needed
```

Comment: Bohemian, A great thanks for your rapid answer. I will have some time to understand it.

Comment: Bohemian, I know that I am asking for a lot here, but I thought that using Xpath was a simple way. like in this tutorial, I was about to work that. https://devqa.io/how-to-parse-json-in-java/ Can you please give me some direction to explain " The simplest way is to parse (deserialise) the json to a java Map<String, Object>, which always succeeds (the values may themselves be maps) using your favourite library (try Jackson or gson)."

Comment: I am fighting hard but now, I have a conflict between libraries.

Comment: OK, I got it >>>>>> Map<String, Object> map;
        map = (HashMap<String, Object>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(responsejson.toString(), LinkedHashMap.class); We have to open the Array I guess, will work on that and bring response. Will add finally the complete script when I am done.

Comment: Is the top level of the json an array? Ie are the first and last chars `[` and `]`?

Comment: Thanks you again, I copy here the json result, {"n_results":1,"page_number":1,"results_per_page":10,"n_pages":1,"available_n_pages":1,"results":[{"id":"FR_DE00114905","language":"fr","headword":{"text":"briser","pos":"verb"},"senses":[{"id":"FR_SE00126791","definition":"réduire en morceaux"},{"id":"FR_SE00002638","definition":"détruire"}]}]}

Comment: Try `List<Map<String, Object>> results = (List<Map<String, Object>>)map.get("results");`

Comment: OK Again thanks!!!! great! It works, List of maps....whaou. I need to work on it. List<Map<String, Object>> results = (List<Map<String, Object>>)map.get("results");
        System.out.println( results.get(0).get("id") );/ output : FR_DE00114905
        System.out.println( results.get(0).get("senses") ); output :  [{id=FR_SE00126791, definition=réduire en morceaux}, {id=FR_SE00002638, definition=détruire}]  how to access this nested array..............

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED List<Map<String, Object>> results33 = (List<Map<String, Object>>)results.get(0).get("senses");
        System.out.println( results33.get(0).get("definition") ); I will make a cleaner code.

Comment: See helper method added to answer. You can write more similar methods. I once build an entire service around this idea and it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

The Json:

```
{"n_results":1,"page_number":1,"results_per_page":10,"n_pages":1,"available_n_pages":1,"results":[{"id":"FR_DE00114905","language":"fr","headword":{"text":"briser","pos":"verb"},"senses":[{"id":"FR_SE00126791","definition":"réduire en morceaux"},{"id":"FR_SE00002638","definition":"détruire"}]}]}
```

Part of the code:

```
String motacherch = "briser";



public void  gettest() throws IOException {



    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=fr&text="+motacherch)
            .basicAuth("user", "password")
            .asJson();
    System.out.println( "---------------------------------------------" );

    JSONObject responsejson = (JSONObject) response.getBody().getObject();
    System.out.println( responsejson);

    System.out.println( "---------------------------------------------" );

    Map<String, Object> map;
    map = (HashMap<String, Object>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(responsejson.toString(), LinkedHashMap.class);
    System.out.println(map.get("results"));

    System.out.println( "---------------------------------------------" );

    List<Map<String, Object>> results = (List<Map<String, Object>>)map.get("results");
    System.out.println( results.get(0).get("id") );
    System.out.println( results.get(0).get("senses") );
    List<Map<String, Object>> results33 = (List<Map<String, Object>>)results.get(0).get("senses");
    System.out.println( results33.get(0).get("definition") );
    System.out.println( results33.get(1).get("definition") );




}
```